# EWP Settings error in PayPal integration process

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am in the process of building my own ecommerce store via PHP and MySQLi. Current testing site is: http://taxreturnsolutions.uk/ecommerce/

I have followed this guide: https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/

I ***HAD*** everything setup and working absolutely fine in that I could click the buy it now button, it would take me to the sandbox site and I could purchase. My SQLi database would be updated with the relevant data etc. However now I keep getting the following message from PayPal Sandbox as follows:

***Note** URL: /webapps/shoppingcart/error?flowlogging_id=7be60528d708&code=EWP_SETTINGS

[image: Paypal Error]

I get this every time I press the buy it now button, however prior to this, it was an intermittent issue for example 3/10 times I used the buy it now button it would present this error and 7/10 times process correctly.

My code for the button is as follows:

```
                    $paypalURL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; //Test PayPal API URL
                    $paypalID = 'ukpwneduk-facilitator@hotmail.com'; //Business Email
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <?php 
                            
                                    if(isset ($_SESSION['login_user'])){
                                            echo "
                                            <form action=' $paypalURL ' method='post' style='text-align: center;'>
                                                <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
                                                <input type='hidden' name='business' value='$paypalID'>
                                                
                                                <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
                                                <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
                                                
                                                <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
                                                <input type='hidden' name='product_name' value='$product_array[$key]['product_name']'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_array[$key]['product_id']'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='product_price' value='$product_array[$key]['product_price']'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='GBP'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://taxreturnsolutions.uk/ecommerce/payments/ipn.php'> 
                                                
                                                <!-- Specify URLs -->
                                                <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://taxreturnsolutions.uk/ecommerce/payments/cancel.php'>
                                                <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://taxreturnsolutions.uk/ecommerce/payments/success.php'>

                                                
                                                <!-- Display the payment button. -->
                                                <input type='image' name='submit' border='0'
                                                src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online'>
                                                <img alt='' border='0' width='1' height='1' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' >
                                            </form> ";
                                            
                                    } else
                                    {
                                    echo "<p style='text-align: center;'><b> Log in</b> to Buy Now </p>";
                                    }   
                                    ?>
```

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I needed to allow un-encrypted websites to make payments to paypal.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you please explain the steps to allow  un-encrypted websites to make payments to paypal.

Answer (score 14):

I believe the problem is in the PayPal configuration.
You need to allow un-encrypted websites to make payments to paypal.
In order to do so, login to your PayPal account then:

Profile & Settings --> My Selling Tools --> Website Preferences

Go down to the section "**Encrypted Website Payments**"
and select "off" to the "Block Non-encrypted Website Payment:"

This should make it working!
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

By default, you accept payments from encrypted and unencrypted buttons. For additional security, you can prevent buyers from sending payments to you through unencrypted buttons.

It seems like you have disabled unencrypted buttons, that's why Paypal is rejecting payments from your buyers who click an unencrypted Buy Now button, an unencrypted Donation button, or an unencrypted Subscription button. This is when you see EWP_SETTINGS error message.

If you previously blocked payments from unencrypted buttons, here’s how to accept all payments:

1. Log in to your PayPal account. Click the Business Profile icon beside    "Log Out" and select Profile and settings.
2. Click My Selling tools.
3. Click Update near 'Website preferences.'
4. Select ‘Off’ next to ‘Block    Non-encrypted Website Payment

Once you turn off this setting you will no longer receive the error message.